# Login page no redirect

Tags: php, mysql, database

At the moment I have a login page, which sends the request to a php file called:

> RequestLoigin.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['username']))
    {
        require '_Authorise/db_connection.php'; // Contains DB connection info, nothing else

        $userName = strtolower($_POST['username']);
        $pass = SHA1($_POST['password']);

            $getUsername = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = '". $userName ."'");
        $user = mysql_fetch_assoc($getUsername);



        if($userName == $user['username'] and $pass == $user['password'])
        {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['key'] = "PRIVATEKEY";
            header('location: PRIVATE DIR/');
        }
        else {
            header('location: ../Hub/?request=incorrect');
            //here is my error
        }
    }
?>
```

This is what I want to change, at the moment it will reload the page and then load up `?request=incorrect`, this shows a small html error alert explaining that the password was incorrect.
What I now want to do is to create an error box on the page without the need to reload the page, how would I do this, and will I have to place this whole script in index and not as a separate script on a new file

Comment: dont use `mysql_` functions and `sha1` for hashing... they are deprecated btw.

Answer (score 0):

jquery Post : https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

```
var jqxhr = $.post( "your-script.php", function(data) {

    if( data == credentials are ok ){

         do something with the box

    }

})
  .done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
  });
```

You can use the callbacks to show / hide / edit your box .

This script has to be [imported] on your html page

Hope it helps